# Regex - pattern capture everything except for pattern [.net]

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to capture anything up to, but not including a particular patter. My actual problem has to do with parsing out information from html, but I am distilling the problem down to an example to, hopefully, clarify my question.

**Source**

```
xaxbxcabcabc
```

**Desired Match**

```
xaxbxc
```

If I use a lookahead the expression will capture the first occurrence

```
.*(?=abc) => xaxbxcabc
```

I would like something along the lines of a negated character class, just for a negated pattern.

```
.*[^abc] //where abc as a pattern instead of a list giving anything but a, b or c
```

I am using http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx for testing

Comment: [Regex is not for parsing HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: You might find http://regexhero.net/tester/ to be a good tester as well.

Comment: @Mormegil's answer to use `*?` is the one you want. Just FYI, it's possible to have a negative lookahead, so your last code block would become `.*(?!abc)`. However, that doesn't seem relevant to your situation, nor is negative lookbehind. `.*(?!abc)` would capture `xaxbxcabcabc` from your sample, and `.*(?<!abc)` would capture `xaxbxcabcab`.

Comment: @Matti - I understand the opposition to using regex to parse html. My case may (or I could easily be wrong) be a bit different. In this case, I am trying to pull specific information out of a specific page that where the html is poorly formatted and contains no semantic signals to the meaning of the content. I am using regex to find contextual indications of the meaning of content. The result will be a brittle data capture function that I know I will have to edit anytime the site owner changes markup. In an ideal world, they would provide an api, or at least generate better html.

Comment: @driis - Thanks for the suggestion, I will check out that tester.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you anchor the regex you'll solve the problem (+ use of lazy quantifier):

```
"^.*?(?=abc)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the solution I decided to go with.

Answer (score 4):

A non-greedy (lazy) quantifier `*?` could be useful here, e.g.

```
^(?<captured>.*?)abc.*$
```

**Edit**: Just to be clear, the explicit capture is (of course) not needed, the really important part is just

```
(.*?)abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wish I could select multiple accepted answers.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx):

```
string result = new Regex("abc.*$").Replace ( input, "" );
```

This will remove everything from the first matching phrase onwards, leaving you with all of the content up until that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the example I used, this would not only work, but probably be the cleanest solution. However, in the case I am working on, it would add a step. I am using a lookbehind to initiate the pattern. So, I would have to match everything after the lookbehind and then do the replace on that match.